# reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: botframework, kubernetes-ingress, lets-encrypt, azure-aks, azure-bot-service

I am a beginner in Kubernetes and using aks to deploy a chatbot. I have used nodejs and Microsoft bot framework to build the bot. I have also deployed the bot to aks using static IP and also given a DNS name to the IP.

Applying ingress controllers and cert-manager I have given an SSL encryption to the DNS name and when I open it in the browser it works stating that the certificate is fake. I want to test my bot in Microsoft bot emulator and other apps like slack, but when I try to run the endpoint on bot emulator I get the error:
[image]

The get request works but when I try to do a post request it doesn't work. I have verified using postman and it doesn't work over there also.
Could someone help me resolve this error.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1388